# How to attach VSCode debugger to azure functions with typescript when using npm start?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, azure-functions

I'm using 'npm start' that works as follows:

```
"watch": "tsc -w",
    "prestart": "npm run build && func extensions install",
    "start:host": "func start --cors *",
    "start": "npm run start:host & npm run watch",
```

This works great, but I can't attach to it through vscode, by launch.json:

{
  "name": "Attach",
  "type": "node",
  "request": "attach",
  "cwd":"${workspaceFolder}",
  "protocol": "auto",
  "port": 9229
}

When I try to attach I get the error:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a Chrome issue with vs code.You must launch Chrome with remote debugging enabled in order for the extension to attach to it.

I have posted an answer for the similar issue with a different scenario, please try and see if it works for you.

You must launch Chrome with remote debugging enabled in order for the extension to attach to it.

**Windows**

Right click the Chrome shortcut, and select properties In the "target" field, append --remote-debugging-port=9229 Or in a command prompt, execute /chrome.exe --remote-debugging-port=9229

**OS X**

In a terminal, execute /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome --remote-debugging-port=9229

Linux

In a terminal, launch google-chrome --remote-debugging-port=9229

https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-chrome-debug